# Make an option selected by default angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I have a dropdown which shows a list of adult passengers `this.adultPaxArr`. I'm required to make the **Select a Passenger**
stay selected by default on page load....

On change event I need to pass the index of the selected object so the static text cannot be part of the array. Is there a way around it?

```
<select (change)="samePax(passengerIndex)" id="samePax{{passengerIndex}}" style="width:325px;" placeholder="Select a Passenger" [(ngModel)]="adultPaxIdx">
 <option [ngValue]="-1">Select a Passenger</option>
  <option *ngFor="let pax of adultPaxArr;let idx = index;" [ngValue]="idx">
      Passenger {{idx + 1}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like...

In HTML

```
<select (change)="samePax(passengerIndex)" id="samePax{{passengerIndex}}" 
style="width:325px;" placeholder="Select a Passenger" [(ngModel)]="adultPaxIdx">
  <option [ngValue]="null">Select a Passenger</option>
  <option *ngFor="let pax of adultPaxArr;let idx = index;" [ngValue]="idx">
     Passenger {{idx + 1}}
  </option>
</select>
```

In TS side

```
adultPaxIdx = null
```

Answer (score 1):

make the `adultPaxId` value as -1 inside the constructor

```
this.adultPaxIdx = -1;
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zuh4gq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add an element with ng-if. The default value and the bool value would be defined in your .ts file.

```
<select (change)="samePax(passengerIndex)" id="samePax{{passengerIndex}}" style="width:325px;" placeholder="Select a Passenger" [(ngModel)]="adultPaxIdx">
 <option [ngValue]="-1">Select a Passenger</option>
  <option *ngFor="let pax of adultPaxArr;let idx = index;" [ngValue]="idx">
      Passenger {{idx + 1}}
  </option>

  # Starts here

  <option *ngIf="!initialized" [ngValue]="-1">
      {{default}}
  </option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to :

```
 <option [ngValue]="undefined">Select a Passenger</option>
```

**[Stackblitz for your ref](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-zdmi29?file=app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

use below code on ngOnInit method

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.adultPaxIdx = -1;
}
```

change your `(change)="samePax(passengerIndex)"` to `(change)="samePax(adultPaxIdx)"` in the html and in ts method add a condition as below

```
samePax(adultPaxIdx)
{
  if(adultPaxIdx !== -1)
  {
    -- your current code
  }
}
```

instead of using index use model value itself